# Floating Button for Support: Shadow is limited and cut off by iframe

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

The [FAB](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button) shadow (bottom right) for the support chat on the [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) pages  seems to be limited by the **iframe** it's embedded in.

This leads to the shadow cutting off very unsightly.
[image: FAB Buttron shadow cuts off]

Comment: What is a *"FAB button"*?

Comment: [FAB](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button) standing for "floating action button", is a prominent action button, mostly in the lower right corner of the screen, always raised with a drop shadow - defined by Google's Material Design Language.